# POST Complex Object to ApiController Subclass

Tags: c#, asp.net-apicontroller

I am working on an API method that should accept an `Image` model object, which has a property `List<Comment> Comments`. The `Image` POSTed from the mobile app works fine but if I include an array of `Comment` objects they aren't showing up on the instance of the `Image`. I'm not super great with C# so any help would be appreciated.

**Image Class**

```
public class Image
{
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public decimal? Lat { get; set; }
    public decimal? Long { get; set; }
    public List<ApiComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**Comment Class**

```
public class ApiComment
{
    [Required]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

**Beginning of ImagesController**

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController
 {
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Image image)
```

Comment: Is `Comments` `null` or empty when the POST occurs?

Comment: Included in the the POST body are valid comments. If I inspect the `Image` instance it shows an empty list.

Comment: Are you posting Json as your request body or in what format?

Comment: Just a side note: `ActionResult` is for MVC, use `IHttpActionResult` for Web API.

Comment: Yea it is the request body coming from the iOS app and is the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's something wrong with the **request body** of your request:

I tried this in fiddler:

```
{ "Comments" : [{ "Comment" : "Hello"}, {"Comment" : "World"}]}
```

And I got two counts for **Comments** in my **WebAPI** Action Method.

Check there are no typo error with the request object you are posting and the Json is valid.

Comment: The body looks like `Comments[][Comment]=Test&Comments[][DateCreated]=2015-07-13T14%3A56%3A53&Comments[][UserId]=105` So I am guessing the missing index in the `[]` brackets is what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry the error seemed to be iOS side, the body was encoded using AFNetworking's AFHttpRequestSerialier and should have been AFJsonRequestSerializer.  You post helped me figure that out though, thanks